# System fails to reach one specific IP address (41.215.xxx.1)

Tags: linux, kernel, routing

Ok, this is driving me crazy now.

I have this RHEL 7 machine that was able to reach this destination IP a few days ago. Its LAN neighbors can see the remote host so the routing between networks is good. Looking at the IP routing table, routing cache and rules there isn't anything unusual that could be causing the problem.

```
default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
172.31.16.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.16.32 metric 100

# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route get 41.215.xxx.1
41.215.xxx.1 via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0 src 172.31.16.32
    cache
```

ICMP is enabled on the box and it can ping other IP addresses.

```
PING 41.215.xxx.13 (41.215.xxx.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 41.215.xxx.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=39 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 41.215.xxx.13: icmp_seq=2 ttl=39 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 41.215.xxx.13: icmp_seq=3 ttl=39 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 41.215.xxx.13: icmp_seq=4 ttl=39 time=130 ms
64 bytes from 41.215.xxx.13: icmp_seq=5 ttl=39 time=130 ms

--- 41.215.xxx.13 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 130.145/130.245/130.399/0.406 ms
# ping 41.215.xxx.1 -c 5
PING 41.215.xxx.1 (41.215.xxx.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 41.215.xxx.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3999ms
```

So as shown above, you get 100% packet loss to this destination.

```
traceroute to 41.215.xxx.1 (41.215.xxx.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

A tshark capture doesn't capture anything going to the destination IP address. The packets aren't even being created aparently or aren't going on the only interface on the box. Yes it may sound crazy :)

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.16.32  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.31.255
        ether 06:b1:d4:07:4e:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 364293720  bytes 168772961614 (157.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 473934683  bytes 95572128708 (89.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: are you allowed to reboot the machine? or at least to put that interface down and up again?

Comment: firewall rule in the output chain?